# Improved Terminal autocomplete funcionality (similar to Matlab's)

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, command-line

If any of you ever used Matlab, you might have noticed the command window functionality in that program. I wonder if it is possible to enable the same functionality in Mac Terminal.

It works like this: suppose you have used two commands previously in this Terminal session. First you used a `cd ~` and then a `ls -la`.

In every *nix terminal, including Mac's, if you hit the `Up Arrow`, it'll first show the `ls -la` command and, if you hit it twice, the `cd ~` command. This is great. But, in Matlab, if you first type the letter `c` and then hit `Up Arrow`, it won't show you `ls`, but instead go directly to `cd ~`. This saves a lot of time when you have big commands and a long list of previously used commands.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a Bash shell, you can hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to do a reverse intelligent search in the history. Start typing the command and the shell will autocomplete with previously entered commands.

Then you can either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command again, use the arrow left or right key to edit the command, or keep pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to cycle through other possible completions.

[image: Reverse intelligent search]

Answer (score 9):

Save this as ~/.inputrc:

```
# make the up and down arrows cycle through commands that match the start of a line
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Option-up would be `\e\e[A` and control-p `\C-p`. You can see the escape sequences of other key combinations by pressing control-v.

Comment: For users who don't yet have `~/.inputrc`, just create one.

Comment: "\e[A": command not found

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can do is type `!` and then the first letter, and it will find the most recent. IE: `cd ~` can be accessed with `!c`

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of the shell. Control-R will do what you describe, but changing to a more modern shell will get you so much more. Take a look at Z-shell (zsh), there is a bit of a learning curve, but it is very powerful.

Comment: I think you mean Control-R.

Answer (score 1):

zsh will complete commands exactly like in your example. You don't even have to do anything other than use it for your shell.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your .cshrc (if you are using tcsh) --

```
  bindkey -k up history-search-backward
  bindkey -k down history-search-forward
```

Then do source ~/.cshrc to get exactly the functionality you describe.

I don't know if there is a .profile equivalent.